# Migration to AndroidX - Where is ResultReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, androidx, android-jetpack

In which new AndroidX dependency is `ResultReceiver`?

I have tried `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1`, assuming that it might be under `v4` due to its previous dependency `android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver`.

I have also tried these:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

I assume there must be a smarter way of finding out the new dependencies?

Source: [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor)

Edit, searching the developer API...

## TraceCompat

[image: TraceCompat Example]

## ReceiverResult

[image: ResultReceiver Example]

Can it be that it isn't in the new system?

Comment: I'm not aware that it was in the old system. I haven't seen a `android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver`. What artifact was it in?

Comment: The package is `android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver` and that is in the artifact `com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1`. You can find it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/support-compat/27.1.1) (or in the latest 28 alpha).

Comment: It is odd that they no longer have `android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver` in the JavaDocs. Curiously, if I look in the `androidx:core:1.0.0-alpha3` AAR manually, I see `android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver`. So, I don't know what their plan is here.

Comment: @Knossos - did you get to know which dependency to add for the ResultReceiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it in `implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'`

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package android.support.v4.os;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.os.Parcelable.Creator;
import android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver.Stub;
import androidx.annotation.RestrictTo;
import androidx.annotation.RestrictTo.Scope;

@RestrictTo({Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP})
public class ResultReceiver implements Parcelable {
...
```

**AND** there's this one:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package android.os;

import android.os.Parcelable.Creator;

public class ResultReceiver implements Parcelable {
```

Comment: It looks to be in `1.0.1` too. Interesting :+1: